# I am trying to assign a certain portion of text to a .txt file in Linux

Tags: linux, command

```
$ echo -e "hello world! \hi World. \hello world" > text1.txt
```

will this work ?

Comment: what exactly did you edit Tim?

Comment: To see the edits to your Q, click on the  link `[edited X hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58628752/revisions) , but notice that the formatting of your Q is now easier to read and the code is in a fixed width font with a grey back ground. ALSO, a good Q will include an example of the required output. As you have included "\" chars, I would want to know, do you expect to see those chars appear in your output? Don't reply in comments, improve the quality of your Q please. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It will work.

But you can try it out on terminal and see what magic happens.
Once you run that. Do `cat text1.txt`